# Sorting and counting matching fields from a model django

Tags: python, django

I have a class of the form:

```
class data:
     person.models.foreignKey("people.person")
     place.models.foreignKey("places.place")
```

and I'm trying to create a dict containing places that have the same person associated with how many connections they have. IE:

```
dict={[place1:place2]:count}
```

so the dict might look like this:

```
dict={[place1:place2]:3, [place1:place3]:2, ect}
```

so far I have:

```
dict={}
datas=data.objects.all()

for data1 in datas:
    for data2 in datas:
        # if dict is empty
        if not dict and data1.person == data2.person and data1.place != data2.place:
            dict[(data1.place, data2.place)]=1
        elif data1.person == data2.person and data1.place != data2.place:
            for assoc, count in dict.items():
                if assoc == (data1.place, data2.place) or assoc == (data2.place, data1.place):
                    count +=1
                else:
                    dict[(data1.place, data2.place)]=1
        else:
            dict[(data1.place, data2.place)]=1
```

this is currently returning completely erroneous relations and never increments count. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use predefined names like dict for your variables. Think that your problem is that you try to increase count variable while you have to increase dict[key] - e.g. dict[key] += 1

```
dct = {}
datas = data.objects.all()

for data1 in datas:
    for data2 in datas:
        # if dict is empty
        if not dct and data1.person == data2.person and data1.place != data2.place:
            dct[(data1.place, data2.place)] = 1
        elif data1.person == data2.person and data1.place != data2.place:
            if (data1.place, data2.place) in dct:
                 dct[(data1.place, data2.place)] += 1
            elif (data2.place, data1.place) in dct:
                 dct[(data2.place, data1.place)] += 1
            else:
                 dct[(data1.place, data2.place)] = 1
        else:
            dct[(data1.place, data2.place)] = 1
```

Comment: this seems to be on the right track. but `dct[(data1.place, data2.place)] += 1` causes a KeyError. Any way to work around this?

Comment: i have added elif statement to handle this case. However if (data1.place, data2.place) and (data2.place, data1.place) is the same then you need to modify code to take this into account

Answer (score 1):

Use annotations. I don't have you model layout, so this is an approximation of the logic. You'll need to tweak it to map to the correct stuff based on your implementation:

```
from django.db.models import Count
places = Place.objects.filter(people=thisguy).annotate(connections=Count('people'))
```

Then you can get the connections count via an attribute on each place:

```
places[0].connections
```